# Use python to check age of Servicenow ticket

Tags: python, date, datetime

Hey all I am new to Python and I'm trying to do the following:

I'm hitting a Servicenow API to get the date that a ticket was created and it comes back in the following format:

2019-06-06 13:11:39

I'm struggling with using datetime, date, strftime, strptime, etc to format the output above into something I can do math on.  Basically I need to close any tickets that are older than 90 days, so the time in the output above can be discarded.  I need to:

1. Get the numerical age in days from the output above based on the current date.
2. If that value is greater than 90, close the ticket.

Here is some of what I have:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
today = date.today()
print(today)  # Print for debug purposes

#API query omitted.....

getdata = response.json()
for item in getdata["result"]:
    print(item["sys_created_on"])
    createdstr = datetime(item["sys_created_on"])
    created = createdstr.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    delta = today - date(created)
    print(delta.days)
    if delta.day > 90:
        #close the ticket
```

....and here is the output:

```
2019-11-07
2019-06-06 13:11:39
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./getUnapprovedSIDs.py", line 32, in <module>
createdstr = datetime(item["sys_created_on"])
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I realize looking at my code is like staring into the sun.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: what does ```item["sys_created_on"]``` output is? I'm not sure that you need 'datetime' before that argument. and also for 'delta', you should use ```datetime.timedelta```. look here: [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

Comment: The output from item["sys_created_on"] is:
2019-06-06 13:11:39

All that I need help with is to somehow convert that into something I can subtract from the current day in order to get the age of the ticket in days.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

created = datetime.strptime(item["sys_created_on"].split(' ')[0], '%Y-%m-%d')
delta = datetime.now() - created
print(delta.days)
```